# CPU not using all threads

Tags: power-management, games, cpu

[CPU monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEjja.png)

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0B1.png)

For some reason my cpu is only using 2 threads when starting a game/process. rest of the threads just stays unused, The cores and threads are all enabled. I configured my power plan to be performance and it's still doing this. Anybody know whats going on?

Comment: Is whatever program you are using capable of using all available CPUs? I.E. is it multithreaded?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Most games are not made to maximise all CPU processes or threads. It's quite hard to do that in modern games. Some games (Genshin Impact included) are also designed to run on mobile devices which commonly have a small number of powerful cores, and another set of lower power cores. The games generally only use one or two cores at most.

So it's basically working as designed.